# Angular13 codelyzer and @angular/core dependency not solving

Tags: angular, angular13, codelyzer

I used Angular 13.
"@angular/core": "~13.3.11"
"codelyzer": "^6.0.2".
When i used npm install it install all dependencies with below warnings. I try npm audit --force so it converts codelyzer version to 0.0.28 and now npm install throw errors that codelyzer@0.0.28 not supported with angular13. So i am in loop now.

> npm i -> throw warning to audit from codelyzer@6.0.2 to @0.0.28

> npm audit --force: change version of codelyzer@0.0.28 now npm i throw errors codelyzer@0.0.28 not supported with angular13.

How to exit from this loop?

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: same in Angular 15. No idea how to fix it

Comment: Not find any solution yet.

Comment: I would recommend use es-lint, codelyzer is deprecated for new versions of angular

Comment: NPM can be strange sometimes. Try deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then run `npm install`. I hate it, but sometimes that does work.

Comment: @AnantDoshi, Did you solve the issue? I am facing same issue!

Comment: @ChrisBarr, not worked! delete both node_modules and package-lock file and reinstalling them, getting same error!

Answer (score 1):

Codelyzer is obsolete, remove it. Install the EsLint package instead:
`ng add @angular-eslint/schematics`